# Basic JQuery API call - how to specify part of the response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm very, very new to APIs (an hour in), and I'm just trying to get to the point where I can output a single part of an API response into console.log - and work from there.

Here's the working code which grabs all the data (for example, to display the last price in Bitcoin:

```
$.ajax({

url: "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/all",

dataType: 'json',

success: function(results){
var gpbvalue = results;

    console.log(gpbvalue);

}

});
```

And here's the data itself: https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/all

How would I specify just the 'last' value under GPB, rather than outputting the entire set of data?

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want.

`console.log(results.GBP.last);`

Comment: @ingredient_mosteroid - what does `console.log(results)` give you? are you sure you wrote _GBP_ instead of _GPB_? you have that typo in your question.

Comment: Ah! That's the mistake. Thank you - and it works perfectly.

Comment: @ingredient_mosteroid - great!! glad to help. please upvote all helpful answers & accept one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The response is a JSON where the first key is a country code and the `last` value is a key under that. If you wanted to pick a specific `last` value you could access it like this:

```
console.log(results['AUD']['last']);
```

Or if you wanted all `last` keys you could do this:

```
for(key in results) {
    console.log(results[key]['last']);
}
```

You can use dot notation but one of the keys `24h_avg` is an invalid variable name (vars can't start with numbers) so named index notation is a better habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gbpvalue = results.GBP.last;
```

or `results["GBP"]["last"]`, both are equivalent.